# MATLAB: latex interpreter font spacing

Tags: matlab, tex

The font spacing in TeX-typeset equations in MATLAB defaults to being highly compressed. Is there a way to increase the amount of spacing, so that, for example, the numerator and denominator of a fraction do not make contact with the line separating the two?

```
plot(1:10,rand(1,10));
set(gca,'FontSize',18);
legend('$\frac{xy}{\exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}$');
set(legend(),'interpreter','latex');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to use some LaTeX trickery.

Long story short, in LaTeX `$ ... $` is used for inline math, but for display math, you should either use `\[ ... \]` or the legacy way of doing the same `$$ ... $$`. For LaTeX documents, don't use the latter, but for MATLAB it should be enough.

The difference between inline math and display math, is like the difference between using backticks (``) and indentation in StackOverflow. The first will show your code in-between text, the latter in-between paragraphs. With math, only display mode math will have decent lay-out for larger formulas.

So the following code should fix your problem:

```
plot(1:10,rand(1,10));
set(gca,'FontSize',18);
legend('$$\frac{xy}{\exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}$$');
set(legend(),'interpreter','latex');
```

If you want even more, you might want to consult the [Not So Short Introduction To LaTeX2e](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english) which gets you started with a lot of the tricks of the LaTeX trade.

**edit:**
What I tend to use as a trick to improve spacing in formulae is using phantoms (`\phantom`, `\vphantom`, `\hphantom`), but `\vspace` or `\vskip` might be a little cleaner to use.

Comment: Great idea, thanks. I should have thought of switching to math display mode. One can also add `\displaystyle` commands at appropriate locations, such as inside a fraction environment. I still notice math symbols touching fraction lines if I have a fraction within a fraction, so please let me know if you know any other chicanery that might ameliorate the symbolic crowding.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the list of properties for the legend, there doesn't seem to be any way of specifying a line spacing that is consistent with automatic positioning. You can fudge the line spacing by enlarging the box, however, by changing the final entry (height) in the OuterPosition property. It seems the placement of the box is based on its bottom-left corner, so if your legend box is in a North position then you will also need to reduce the second entry (y-position) by an equal amount.

In this example I increase the height of a North-positioned legend box by 25% (which I have found that gives nice results), which increases the line spacing.

```
h = legend(s1,s2,s3, 'location', 'northeast');
set(h, 'fontsize', 16, 'interpreter', 'latex')

outerposition = get(h, 'OuterPosition');
delta_h = 0.25*outerposition(4);
outerposition(2) = outerposition(2) - delta_h;
outerposition(4) = outerposition(4) + delta_h;
set(h, 'OuterPosition', outerposition)
```

You have to be wary about resizing the figure after running this code fragment, since changing the OuterPosition property clears the automatic placement of the box with respect to the plot axes. If you resize the figure the legend box will go walkabouts.